# Run time error for dynamic memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++

I am a newbie for OOP concepts and while trying to solve Project Euler [Problem 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7), to find 10001th prime number, I tried to do it using a class but encountered 2 major errors.

1. instantiating the class `prime_n`
2. initializing its argument

I have posted the code here for reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

class prime_n
{
     int j,k;
     int n;
     int *store;

     public:
     prime_n(int num)
     {
         n=num;
         store[n];
     }   
     static int isPrime(int j)
     {
          for(int i=2;i*i<=j;i++)
          {
               if(j%i==0) return 0;
          }
          return 1;
     }
     void find_n()
     {
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
               store[i]=0;
          }
          store[0]=2;
          j=3;
          k=1;
          while(store[n-1]==0)
          {
               if(isPrime(j)) store[k++]=j;
               j+=2;
          }
     }
     int get_num()
     {
     int value=store[n-1];
     return value;
     }   
};   

int main()
{
     int num, req_num;
     printf("Enter the position at which prime number is to be found ");
     scanf("%d",&num);
     printf("\nnumber = %d",num);

     prime_n p = new prime_n(num);

     req_num = p.get_num();
     printf("The required prime number is %d\n",req_num);
     return 0;
}
```

It would be a great help if someone could help me figure out where I am actually going wrong. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: instead of `int* store`, use a `std::vector<int> store`. the statement `store[n];`, if not optimized completely away, attempts to index the array pointed to by the `store` pointer, which is not yet initialized, which means you have **undefined behavior**, which is ungood. you avoid that and some other nasty problems by using `std::vector` instead of raw array and pointer.

Comment: Initially, I had thought of using an array too but then I thought that for large numbers, using vector array may be expensive. Is n't that true?

Comment: @Neha A vector isn't more expensive than an array you manage yourself. (Well, it's probably one pointer larger, but that's independent of the size of the vector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a constructor:

```
 prime_n(int num)
 {
     n=num;
     store[n];
 }
```

I think you are under the impression that `store[n]` creates an array with n elements, but that is not so; it attempts to access the (n+1)th element of an an array. Since store does not point anywhere (we are in the constructor, after all), the program crashes.

You probably want to write `store = new int[num]` instead.

And then I cannot see any call to find_n() originating from get_num() which is called in main(), so that your program would for now just return a random value.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
prime_n p(num);
```

or (not recommended in this particular case)

```
prime_n * p = new prime_n(num);
// some other code
req_num = p->get_num(); // note the -> operator replacing . in case of pointers

delete p;
```

The first case declares `p` on stack and it is automatically deallocated when the program leaves the scope (`main` function in this case)

The second one allocates space on heap and `p` is the pointer to it. You have to deallocate the memory manually.

As for your second question, the C++ way would be

```
#include <iostream>

...
int num;
std::cout << "Enter the position at which prime number is to be found "
std::cin >> num;
std::cout << std::endl << "Number = " << num << std::endl;
```

Comment: And you really shouldn't use head-allocation if you cannot explain why you would need it.